# What is the difference between "safe" and "vault"?

Tags: meaning, nouns

What is the difference between *safe* and *vault*, where both the words refer to a place where to put things you want to keep safe?

As additional question, why does *vault* seem more frequently used in computer jargon? For example, the Mac OS X has a *File vault*, and *vault* is the word used from anti-virus programs to refer to a place where infected files are kept.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A safe connotes something smaller than a vault, and may be movable, while a vault is generally built in-place and would be torn down rather than moved.

The computer jargon use of *vault* may be due to its connotation of greater security.  It is also attractive because it is less common, and is only a noun (in this sense) and thus quicker to interpret, whereas *safe* can be noun, verb, or adjective (and heavily used in the latter sense in the computer security context).

Answer (score 9):

A *safe* is usually smaller than a *vault*. Safes are often portable, or at least movable, while vaults often are entire rooms.

Comment: +1 Much like boats and ships, you can put a safe in a vault, but not a vault in a safe.

Comment: But it *is* possible to vault over a safe in a boat in a vault on a ship!

Comment: @horatio: It's *possible*, but it isn't safe.

Comment: Additionally, *vault* is sometimes used metaphorically to refer to protected electronic storage, while I've never heard *safe* used that way.

Comment: @JSBangs: However Microsoft Visual SourceSafe is/was a product for storing source code, though it is not clear that "safe" doesn't refer to safety.

Comment: @JSBangs, @horatio: Let's not forget the fact that the OP was talking about things someone *wants* to keep safe. Presumably that doesn't include Microsoft products. I'm just sayin' ... :)

Answer (score 0):

A safe has one layer of steel surrounding the interior shell. The Department of Justice requires a minimum of 12 gauge steel to call it a safe. Otherwise, it's a cabinet. A quality safe will have c-rated fire board underneath the steel to protect against fire. A vault has a layer of steel on the outside, fire board and then an additional layer of steel on the inside. A good quality safe with 7 gauge (3/16") steel that's 60x40x28 will run about $3000 before adding any options or upgrades. That same safe made into a vault by adding that second layer will cost about $3800. If you were to add a layer of 304 stainless steel, it would be impervious to torch cutting and would cost about $5400.

Safe = one layer of steel

Vault = 2 or more layers of steel